# Creating a dataframe by repeating each column a certain number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to turn the following dataframe:

```
ID   | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  |
1    | 3  | 1  | 2  | 1  | 0  |
2    | 0  | 1  | 2  | 5  | 2  |
3    | 2  | 2  | 5  | 3  | 10 |
```

into one that has each column name as the new value, repeated the number of times specified in the value. So, three rows of 'A', one rows of 'B', etc.:

```
ID | VALUE |
1  | A     |
1  | A     |
1  | A     |
1  | B     |
1  | C     |
1  | C     |
1  | D     |
2  | B     |
2  | C     |
2  | C     |
...
```

So far I've been playing in loops, building up a new dataframe but it's taking forever (100,000 original rows, and values of 100+) and just feels wrong. Have looked at `melt` and `explode` but it's not quite what I'm after. Any elegant solutions to doing this?

```
data = [{'ID': 1, 'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 0},
        {'ID': 2, 'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'D': 5, 'E': 2},
        {'ID': 3, 'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 5, 'D': 3, 'E': 10}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: @sammywemmy - not quite. I need a row with `ID` repeated 3 times, and the value `A` in that cell. Then `ID=1` repeated 1 time, with the value `B` in that cell. Essentially looking up the row-column value, and repeating the row-column name that many times

Comment: @sammywemmy - what I see is 3 rows of `A` each one with an `ID` of 1, 2, 3. What I'm after is 5 rows of `A`, 3 with the `ID=1` and 2 with an `ID=3`. The original dataframe tells me how many rows of `A` I need repeated with that `ID`

Comment: @sammywemmy - I did that, but the number of rows is incorrect. I don't need 3 rows for every column. I need `x` rows for each `ID-Column` combination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.columns.repeat`:

```
df.apply(df.columns.repeat, axis=1).explode()
```

Output:

```
ID
1    A
1    A
1    A
1    B
1    C
1    C
1    D
2    B
...
3    E
3    E
3    E
dtype: object
```

Comment: You make that seem so easy. I wasn't aware of `repeat` and that was the key

Comment: @Carl I'm still working on it a bit since i'm not quite sure about the performance when it comes to 100K+ rows. How does it fit into your actual case?

Comment: it produces the correct result. I'll run it with the larger dataset later and see how it goes

Comment: @Carl sounds great. Do let me know ;)

Comment: Just ran it, and it runs pretty fast for my needs. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Try with `melt`, then `repeat`

```
s = df.melt('ID')
s = s.reindex(s.index.repeat(s.pop('value')))
s
Out[41]: 
    ID variable
0    1        A
0    1        A
0    1        A
2    3        A
2    3        A
3    1        B
4    2        B
5    3        B
5    3        B
6    1        C
6    1        C
7    2        C
7    2        C
8    3        C
8    3        C
8    3        C
8    3        C
8    3        C
9    1        D
10   2        D
10   2        D
10   2        D
10   2        D
10   2        D
11   3        D
11   3        D
11   3        D
13   2        E
13   2        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
14   3        E
```